# How do I extract the TIFF preview from an EPS file using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, tiff, eps

EPS files can include embedded TIFF (and rarely WMF) previews for easy rendering in environments which do not have PostScript available. (See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulated_PostScript#EPS_previews) for more info.)

Given such an EPS, how can I extract the TIFF into a separate file using MATLAB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```matlab
% Define the source EPS file and the desired target TIFF to create.
source = 'ode_nonneg1.eps';
target = 'ode_nonneg1.tif';

% Read in the EPS file.
f = fopen(source,'rb');
d = fread(f,'uint8');
fclose(f);

% Check the header to verify it is a TIFF.
if ~isequal(d(1:4),[197;208;211;198])
    error 'This does not appear to be a vaild TIFF file.'
end

% Extract the TIFF data location from the headers.
tiffStart = sum(d(21:24).*256.^(0:3)')+1;
tiffLength = sum(d(25:28).*256.^(0:3)');

% Write the TIFF file.
f = fopen(target,'w');
fwrite(f,d(tiffStart:tiffStart-1+tiffLength),'uint8','b');
fclose(f);
```

Comment: +1 perhaps you could read just the TIFF preview without having to read the entire EPS file in memory (by reading the first 28 bytes from the file then using `fseek` and reading the specified range)