# Convert EPS with TIFF (EPT) to png, keeping transparent background

Tags: php, imagemagick, eps

I know there is already a question about setting [transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11115408/956397) background color but the answer is a workaround. It does not set the background it only makes one color transparent. If I use `-transparent white` not only the background but also white colors of the image getting transparent. My EPS file:

```
$ identify test.eps
test.eps EPT 4280x8000 4280x8000+0+0 16-bit sRGB 16.13MB 0.031u 0:00.034
```

As you can see I have a EPT file, ImageMagic [tells me](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php) this means "Adobe Encapsulated PostScript Interchange format with TIFF preview".

The TIFF does have the transparent background so maybe I need to extract the TIFF first? Can ImageMagic do that or do I need [epstool](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/epstool.1.html)? I there a way to extract the TIFF with php? I found a [extract using matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751052/how-do-i-extract-the-tiff-preview-from-an-eps-file-using-matlab).

I managed to extract the tiff using [epstool](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/epstool.1.html):

```
$ epstool --extract-preview test.eps test.tiff
```

If I view the tiff I don't see any transparency but identify shows `Transparent color: black` but `Background color: white` so I guess this is shown to me as white.

I also tried to convert the eps using ghostscript. Later on I read the ImageMagick's convert uses nearly the same and you can make it visible with `-verbose`:

```
$ convert -verbose test.eps test.png
[ghostscript library] Files/gs/gs9.05/bin/gswin64c.exe" -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=5000
00000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=pngalpha" -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 "-r72x72" -g4280x8000
-dEPSCrop  "-sOutputFile=test.png test.eps
```

**How to convert a EPS with TIFF (EPT) to png and keep transparency?**

Here you see `identify test.eps` and `identify test.tiff`:

```
  $ identify -verbose test.eps
  Image: test.eps
  Format: EPT (Encapsulated PostScript with TIFF preview)
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 4280x8000+0+0
  Resolution: 72x72
  Print size: 59.4444x111.111
  Units: Undefined
  Type: TrueColorAlpha
  Endianess: Undefined
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Depth: 16/8-bit
  Channel depth:
    red: 8-bit
    green: 8-bit
    blue: 8-bit
    alpha: 1-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Red:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 65535 (1)
      mean: 45066.7 (0.687674)
      standard deviation: 28738.7 (0.438525)
      kurtosis: -1.36435
      skewness: -0.753428
    Green:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 65535 (1)
      mean: 47254.3 (0.721054)
      standard deviation: 25071.5 (0.382566)
      kurtosis: -1.40104
      skewness: -0.719388
    Blue:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 65535 (1)
      mean: 56179.5 (0.857245)
      standard deviation: 17871.7 (0.272705)
      kurtosis: 3.22691
      skewness: -2.12993
    Alpha:
      min: 65535 (1)
      max: 65535 (1)
      mean: 65535 (1)
      standard deviation: 0 (0)
      kurtosis: 0
      skewness: 0
  Image statistics:
    Overall:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 65535 (1)
      mean: 37125.1 (0.566493)
      standard deviation: 21058.8 (0.321337)
      kurtosis: 1.91933
      skewness: -0.72419
  Rendering intent: Perceptual
  Gamma: 0.454545
  Chromaticity:
    red primary: (0.64,0.33)
    green primary: (0.3,0.6)
    blue primary: (0.15,0.06)
    white point: (0.3127,0.329)
  Background color: white
  Border color: srgba(223,223,223,1)
  Matte color: grey74
  Transparent color: none
  Interlace: None
  Intensity: Undefined
  Compose: Over
  Page geometry: 4280x8000+0+0
  Dispose: Undefined
  Iterations: 0
  Compression: Undefined
  Orientation: Undefined
  Properties:
    date:create: 2014-01-23T09:10:56+01:00
    date:modify: 2014-01-23T09:11:08+01:00
    dc:format: image/epsf
    photoshop:ColorMode: 3
    ps:HiResBoundingBox: 4280x8000+0+0
    ps:Level: Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
    signature: 8f39a1c8121b87901361e7b03bdfa7fc5363602129c9733aabc39c5b25fbcbe8
    stRef:documentID: uuid:077BE8BAC383E111A613E638E2B2EB83
    stRef:instanceID: xmp.iid:4a2e9641-c2df-4571-90d7-47b700e164fd
    stRef:originalDocumentID: uuid:077BE8BAC383E111A613E638E2B2EB83
    xmp:CreateDate: 2012-04-11T12:48:19+02:00
    xmp:CreatorTool: Adobe Photoshop CS2 Windows
    xmp:MetadataDate: 2013-12-16T09:41:20+01:00
    xmp:ModifyDate: 2013-12-16T09:41:20+01:00
    xmpMM:DocumentID: uuid:077BE8BAC383E111A613E638E2B2EB83
    xmpMM:InstanceID: xmp.iid:735c11c3-22a5-4ac5-9ea9-47b4370aeb1b
    xmpMM:OriginalDocumentID: uuid:077BE8BAC383E111A613E638E2B2EB83
    xmpRights:Marked: False
  Profiles:
    Profile-8bim: 6642 bytes
    Profile-exif: 398 bytes
    Profile-iptc: 15 bytes
      City[1,90]: 0x00000000: 254700                                        -%
      unknown[2,0]:
    Profile-xmp: 15362 bytes
  Artifacts:
    filename: test.eps
    verbose: true
  Tainted: False
  Filesize: 16.13MB
  Number pixels: 34.24M
  Pixels per second: 25.44MB
  User time: 1.342u
  Elapsed time: 0:02.346
  Version: ImageMagick 6.8.7-10 Q16 x64 2013-12-08 http://www.imagemagick.org
=============================================================================
=============================================================================
=============================================================================
$ identify test.tiff
Image: test.tiff
  Format: TIFF (Tagged Image File Format)
  Mime type: image/tiff
  Class: PseudoClass
  Geometry: 274x512+0+0
  Resolution: 4.6099x4.6099
  Print size: 59.4373x111.065
  Units: PixelsPerInch
  Type: Palette
  Base type: Palette
  Endianess: MSB
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Depth: 4-bit
  Channel depth:
    red: 4-bit
    green: 4-bit
    blue: 4-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Red:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 15 (1)
      mean: 10.3128 (0.687522)
      standard deviation: 6.5204 (0.434694)
      kurtosis: -1.33441
      skewness: -0.754224
    Green:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 15 (1)
      mean: 10.8132 (0.720879)
      standard deviation: 5.69458 (0.379639)
      kurtosis: -1.33212
      skewness: -0.730642
    Blue:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 15 (1)
      mean: 12.8588 (0.857254)
      standard deviation: 4.08342 (0.272228)
      kurtosis: 3.08512
      skewness: -2.08272
  Image statistics:
    Overall:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 15 (1)
      mean: 11.3283 (0.755218)
      standard deviation: 5.52625 (0.368416)
      kurtosis: -0.401253
      skewness: -1.15836
  Colors: 128
  Histogram:
       265: (  0,  0,  0) #000000 black
        36: (  0,  0, 17) #000011 srgb(0,0,17)
         3: (  0,  0, 51) #000033 srgb(0,0,51)
        23: (  0,  0, 68) #000044 srgb(0,0,68)
        71: (  0,  0, 85) #000055 srgb(0,0,85)
        58: (  0,  0,102) #000066 srgb(0,0,102)
        77: (  0,  0,119) #000077 srgb(0,0,119)
       134: (  0,  0,136) #000088 srgb(0,0,136)
       206: (  0,  0,153) #000099 srgb(0,0,153)
       298: (  0,  0,170) #0000AA srgb(0,0,170)
       692: (  0,  0,187) #0000BB srgb(0,0,187)
       458: (  0,  0,204) #0000CC srgb(0,0,204)
      1116: (  0,  0,221) #0000DD srgb(0,0,221)
       592: (  0,  0,238) #0000EE srgb(0,0,238)
        28: (  0, 17,  0) #001100 srgb(0,17,0)
         2: (  0, 34,  0) #002200 srgb(0,34,0)
         1: (  0, 51, 51) #003333 srgb(0,51,51)
        48: (  0, 51,102) #003366 srgb(0,51,102)
      1315: (  0, 51,153) #003399 srgb(0,51,153)
     18344: (  0, 51,204) #0033CC srgb(0,51,204)
      3003: (  0, 51,255) #0033FF srgb(0,51,255)
         1: (  0,102,153) #006699 srgb(0,102,153)
       734: (  0,102,204) #0066CC srgb(0,102,204)
       654: (  0,102,255) #0066FF srgb(0,102,255)
        19: ( 17,  0,  0) #110000 srgb(17,0,0)
      2271: ( 17, 17, 17) #111111 srgb(17,17,17)
      3677: ( 34, 34, 34) #222222 srgb(34,34,34)
         1: ( 51,  0,153) #330099 srgb(51,0,153)
        13: ( 51,  0,204) #3300CC srgb(51,0,204)
        67: ( 51, 51,  0) #333300 srgb(51,51,0)
      2375: ( 51, 51, 51) #333333 grey20
        33: ( 51, 51,102) #333366 srgb(51,51,102)
       171: ( 51, 51,153) #333399 srgb(51,51,153)
      2039: ( 51, 51,204) #3333CC srgb(51,51,204)
      1329: ( 51, 51,255) #3333FF srgb(51,51,255)
         1: ( 51,102,  0) #336600 srgb(51,102,0)
        10: ( 51,102,102) #336666 srgb(51,102,102)
       145: ( 51,102,153) #336699 srgb(51,102,153)
       963: ( 51,102,204) #3366CC srgb(51,102,204)
       585: ( 51,102,255) #3366FF srgb(51,102,255)
      1504: ( 68, 68, 68) #444444 srgb(68,68,68)
       893: ( 85, 85, 85) #555555 srgb(85,85,85)
         1: (102,  0,102) #660066 srgb(102,0,102)
         9: (102, 51,  0) #663300 srgb(102,51,0)
        10: (102, 51, 51) #663333 srgb(102,51,51)
         9: (102, 51,102) #663366 srgb(102,51,102)
        16: (102, 51,153) #663399 srgb(102,51,153)
         4: (102, 51,204) #6633CC srgb(102,51,204)
         9: (102, 51,255) #6633FF srgb(102,51,255)
        87: (102,102,  0) #666600 srgb(102,102,0)
        50: (102,102, 51) #666633 srgb(102,102,51)
       289: (102,102,102) #666666 grey40
        74: (102,102,153) #666699 srgb(102,102,153)
       518: (102,102,204) #6666CC srgb(102,102,204)
       468: (102,102,255) #6666FF srgb(102,102,255)
         1: (102,153,  0) #669900 srgb(102,153,0)
         1: (102,153, 51) #669933 srgb(102,153,51)
         4: (102,153,102) #669966 srgb(102,153,102)
        29: (102,153,153) #669999 srgb(102,153,153)
       342: (102,153,204) #6699CC srgb(102,153,204)
       116: (102,153,255) #6699FF srgb(102,153,255)
       126: (119,119,119) #777777 srgb(119,119,119)
        71: (136,136,136) #888888 srgb(136,136,136)
         1: (153,  0, 51) #990033 srgb(153,0,51)
        21: (153,  0,102) #990066 srgb(153,0,102)
        37: (153, 51,102) #993366 srgb(153,51,102)
        49: (153,102,  0) #996600 srgb(153,102,0)
         9: (153,102, 51) #996633 srgb(153,102,51)
         1: (153,102,102) #996666 srgb(153,102,102)
         1: (153,102,153) #996699 srgb(153,102,153)
         1: (153,102,204) #9966CC srgb(153,102,204)
        11: (153,102,255) #9966FF srgb(153,102,255)
       151: (153,153,  0) #999900 srgb(153,153,0)
        71: (153,153, 51) #999933 srgb(153,153,51)
        54: (153,153,102) #999966 srgb(153,153,102)
        72: (153,153,153) #999999 grey60
       463: (153,153,204) #9999CC srgb(153,153,204)
       462: (153,153,255) #9999FF srgb(153,153,255)
         8: (153,204, 51) #99CC33 srgb(153,204,51)
        93: (153,204,204) #99CCCC srgb(153,204,204)
       166: (153,204,255) #99CCFF srgb(153,204,255)
        70: (170,170,170) #AAAAAA srgb(170,170,170)
        88: (187,187,187) #BBBBBB srgb(187,187,187)
       178: (204,  0, 51) #CC0033 srgb(204,0,51)
         1: (204,  0,102) #CC0066 srgb(204,0,102)
        19: (204, 51, 51) #CC3333 srgb(204,51,51)
         4: (204, 51,102) #CC3366 srgb(204,51,102)
         1: (204,102,102) #CC6666 srgb(204,102,102)
         1: (204,102,153) #CC6699 srgb(204,102,153)
       116: (204,153,  0) #CC9900 srgb(204,153,0)
        38: (204,153, 51) #CC9933 srgb(204,153,51)
         1: (204,153,102) #CC9966 srgb(204,153,102)
         1: (204,153,153) #CC9999 srgb(204,153,153)
         1: (204,153,204) #CC99CC srgb(204,153,204)
         6: (204,153,255) #CC99FF srgb(204,153,255)
       207: (204,204,  0) #CCCC00 srgb(204,204,0)
        87: (204,204, 51) #CCCC33 srgb(204,204,51)
         2: (204,204,102) #CCCC66 srgb(204,204,102)
        13: (204,204,153) #CCCC99 srgb(204,204,153)
       156: (204,204,204) #CCCCCC grey80
       625: (204,204,255) #CCCCFF srgb(204,204,255)
         2: (204,255,  0) #CCFF00 srgb(204,255,0)
         1: (204,255,153) #CCFF99 srgb(204,255,153)
         2: (204,255,204) #CCFFCC srgb(204,255,204)
         3: (204,255,255) #CCFFFF srgb(204,255,255)
         4: (221,  0,  0) #DD0000 srgb(221,0,0)
       321: (221,221,221) #DDDDDD srgb(221,221,221)
         5: (238,  0,  0) #EE0000 srgb(238,0,0)
      1433: (238,238,238) #EEEEEE srgb(238,238,238)
       213: (255,  0, 51) #FF0033 srgb(255,0,51)
        20: (255, 51, 51) #FF3333 srgb(255,51,51)
        24: (255, 51,102) #FF3366 srgb(255,51,102)
        12: (255,102,102) #FF6666 srgb(255,102,102)
         6: (255,102,153) #FF6699 srgb(255,102,153)
        21: (255,153,153) #FF9999 srgb(255,153,153)
         7: (255,153,204) #FF99CC srgb(255,153,204)
      1806: (255,204,  0) #FFCC00 srgb(255,204,0)
        70: (255,204, 51) #FFCC33 srgb(255,204,51)
        27: (255,204,102) #FFCC66 srgb(255,204,102)
         9: (255,204,153) #FFCC99 srgb(255,204,153)
        25: (255,204,204) #FFCCCC srgb(255,204,204)
         2: (255,204,255) #FFCCFF srgb(255,204,255)
       587: (255,255,  0) #FFFF00 yellow
        27: (255,255, 51) #FFFF33 srgb(255,255,51)
        41: (255,255,102) #FFFF66 srgb(255,255,102)
        90: (255,255,153) #FFFF99 srgb(255,255,153)
        13: (255,255,204) #FFFFCC srgb(255,255,204)
     85742: (255,255,255) #FFFFFF white
  Colormap entries: 256
  Colormap:
         0: (255,255,255) #FFFFFF white
         1: (255,255,204) #FFFFCC srgb(255,255,204)
         2: (255,255,153) #FFFF99 srgb(255,255,153)
         3: (255,255,102) #FFFF66 srgb(255,255,102)
         4: (255,255, 51) #FFFF33 srgb(255,255,51)
         5: (255,255,  0) #FFFF00 yellow
         6: (255,204,255) #FFCCFF srgb(255,204,255)
         7: (255,204,204) #FFCCCC srgb(255,204,204)
         8: (255,204,153) #FFCC99 srgb(255,204,153)
         9: (255,204,102) #FFCC66 srgb(255,204,102)
        10: (255,204, 51) #FFCC33 srgb(255,204,51)
        11: (255,204,  0) #FFCC00 srgb(255,204,0)
        12: (255,153,255) #FF99FF srgb(255,153,255)
        13: (255,153,204) #FF99CC srgb(255,153,204)
        14: (255,153,153) #FF9999 srgb(255,153,153)
        15: (255,153,102) #FF9966 srgb(255,153,102)
        16: (255,153, 51) #FF9933 srgb(255,153,51)
        17: (255,153,  0) #FF9900 srgb(255,153,0)
        18: (255,102,255) #FF66FF srgb(255,102,255)
        19: (255,102,204) #FF66CC srgb(255,102,204)
        20: (255,102,153) #FF6699 srgb(255,102,153)
        21: (255,102,102) #FF6666 srgb(255,102,102)
        22: (255,102, 51) #FF6633 srgb(255,102,51)
        23: (255,102,  0) #FF6600 srgb(255,102,0)
        24: (255, 51,255) #FF33FF srgb(255,51,255)
        25: (255, 51,204) #FF33CC srgb(255,51,204)
        26: (255, 51,153) #FF3399 srgb(255,51,153)
        27: (255, 51,102) #FF3366 srgb(255,51,102)
        28: (255, 51, 51) #FF3333 srgb(255,51,51)
        29: (255, 51,  0) #FF3300 srgb(255,51,0)
        30: (255,  0,255) #FF00FF magenta
        31: (255,  0,204) #FF00CC srgb(255,0,204)
        32: (255,  0,153) #FF0099 srgb(255,0,153)
        33: (255,  0,102) #FF0066 srgb(255,0,102)
        34: (255,  0, 51) #FF0033 srgb(255,0,51)
        35: (255,  0,  0) #FF0000 red
        36: (204,255,255) #CCFFFF srgb(204,255,255)
        37: (204,255,204) #CCFFCC srgb(204,255,204)
        38: (204,255,153) #CCFF99 srgb(204,255,153)
        39: (204,255,102) #CCFF66 srgb(204,255,102)
        40: (204,255, 51) #CCFF33 srgb(204,255,51)
        41: (204,255,  0) #CCFF00 srgb(204,255,0)
        42: (204,204,255) #CCCCFF srgb(204,204,255)
        43: (204,204,204) #CCCCCC grey80
        44: (204,204,153) #CCCC99 srgb(204,204,153)
        45: (204,204,102) #CCCC66 srgb(204,204,102)
        46: (204,204, 51) #CCCC33 srgb(204,204,51)
        47: (204,204,  0) #CCCC00 srgb(204,204,0)
        48: (204,153,255) #CC99FF srgb(204,153,255)
        49: (204,153,204) #CC99CC srgb(204,153,204)
        50: (204,153,153) #CC9999 srgb(204,153,153)
        51: (204,153,102) #CC9966 srgb(204,153,102)
        52: (204,153, 51) #CC9933 srgb(204,153,51)
        53: (204,153,  0) #CC9900 srgb(204,153,0)
        54: (204,102,255) #CC66FF srgb(204,102,255)
        55: (204,102,204) #CC66CC srgb(204,102,204)
        56: (204,102,153) #CC6699 srgb(204,102,153)
        57: (204,102,102) #CC6666 srgb(204,102,102)
        58: (204,102, 51) #CC6633 srgb(204,102,51)
        59: (204,102,  0) #CC6600 srgb(204,102,0)
        60: (204, 51,255) #CC33FF srgb(204,51,255)
        61: (204, 51,204) #CC33CC srgb(204,51,204)
        62: (204, 51,153) #CC3399 srgb(204,51,153)
        63: (204, 51,102) #CC3366 srgb(204,51,102)
        64: (204, 51, 51) #CC3333 srgb(204,51,51)
        65: (204, 51,  0) #CC3300 srgb(204,51,0)
        66: (204,  0,255) #CC00FF srgb(204,0,255)
        67: (204,  0,204) #CC00CC srgb(204,0,204)
        68: (204,  0,153) #CC0099 srgb(204,0,153)
        69: (204,  0,102) #CC0066 srgb(204,0,102)
        70: (204,  0, 51) #CC0033 srgb(204,0,51)
        71: (204,  0,  0) #CC0000 srgb(204,0,0)
        72: (153,255,255) #99FFFF srgb(153,255,255)
        73: (153,255,204) #99FFCC srgb(153,255,204)
        74: (153,255,153) #99FF99 srgb(153,255,153)
        75: (153,255,102) #99FF66 srgb(153,255,102)
        76: (153,255, 51) #99FF33 srgb(153,255,51)
        77: (153,255,  0) #99FF00 srgb(153,255,0)
        78: (153,204,255) #99CCFF srgb(153,204,255)
        79: (153,204,204) #99CCCC srgb(153,204,204)
        80: (153,204,153) #99CC99 srgb(153,204,153)
        81: (153,204,102) #99CC66 srgb(153,204,102)
        82: (153,204, 51) #99CC33 srgb(153,204,51)
        83: (153,204,  0) #99CC00 srgb(153,204,0)
        84: (153,153,255) #9999FF srgb(153,153,255)
        85: (153,153,204) #9999CC srgb(153,153,204)
        86: (153,153,153) #999999 grey60
        87: (153,153,102) #999966 srgb(153,153,102)
        88: (153,153, 51) #999933 srgb(153,153,51)
        89: (153,153,  0) #999900 srgb(153,153,0)
        90: (153,102,255) #9966FF srgb(153,102,255)
        91: (153,102,204) #9966CC srgb(153,102,204)
        92: (153,102,153) #996699 srgb(153,102,153)
        93: (153,102,102) #996666 srgb(153,102,102)
        94: (153,102, 51) #996633 srgb(153,102,51)
        95: (153,102,  0) #996600 srgb(153,102,0)
        96: (153, 51,255) #9933FF srgb(153,51,255)
        97: (153, 51,204) #9933CC srgb(153,51,204)
        98: (153, 51,153) #993399 srgb(153,51,153)
        99: (153, 51,102) #993366 srgb(153,51,102)
       100: (153, 51, 51) #993333 srgb(153,51,51)
       101: (153, 51,  0) #993300 srgb(153,51,0)
       102: (153,  0,255) #9900FF srgb(153,0,255)
       103: (153,  0,204) #9900CC srgb(153,0,204)
       104: (153,  0,153) #990099 srgb(153,0,153)
       105: (153,  0,102) #990066 srgb(153,0,102)
       106: (153,  0, 51) #990033 srgb(153,0,51)
       107: (153,  0,  0) #990000 srgb(153,0,0)
       108: (102,255,255) #66FFFF srgb(102,255,255)
       109: (102,255,204) #66FFCC srgb(102,255,204)
       110: (102,255,153) #66FF99 srgb(102,255,153)
       111: (102,255,102) #66FF66 srgb(102,255,102)
       112: (102,255, 51) #66FF33 srgb(102,255,51)
       113: (102,255,  0) #66FF00 srgb(102,255,0)
       114: (102,204,255) #66CCFF srgb(102,204,255)
       115: (102,204,204) #66CCCC srgb(102,204,204)
       116: (102,204,153) #66CC99 srgb(102,204,153)
       117: (102,204,102) #66CC66 srgb(102,204,102)
       118: (102,204, 51) #66CC33 srgb(102,204,51)
       119: (102,204,  0) #66CC00 srgb(102,204,0)
       120: (102,153,255) #6699FF srgb(102,153,255)
       121: (102,153,204) #6699CC srgb(102,153,204)
       122: (102,153,153) #669999 srgb(102,153,153)
       123: (102,153,102) #669966 srgb(102,153,102)
       124: (102,153, 51) #669933 srgb(102,153,51)
       125: (102,153,  0) #669900 srgb(102,153,0)
       126: (102,102,255) #6666FF srgb(102,102,255)
       127: (102,102,204) #6666CC srgb(102,102,204)
       128: (102,102,153) #666699 srgb(102,102,153)
       129: (102,102,102) #666666 grey40
       130: (102,102, 51) #666633 srgb(102,102,51)
       131: (102,102,  0) #666600 srgb(102,102,0)
       132: (102, 51,255) #6633FF srgb(102,51,255)
       133: (102, 51,204) #6633CC srgb(102,51,204)
       134: (102, 51,153) #663399 srgb(102,51,153)
       135: (102, 51,102) #663366 srgb(102,51,102)
       136: (102, 51, 51) #663333 srgb(102,51,51)
       137: (102, 51,  0) #663300 srgb(102,51,0)
       138: (102,  0,255) #6600FF srgb(102,0,255)
       139: (102,  0,204) #6600CC srgb(102,0,204)
       140: (102,  0,153) #660099 srgb(102,0,153)
       141: (102,  0,102) #660066 srgb(102,0,102)
       142: (102,  0, 51) #660033 srgb(102,0,51)
       143: (102,  0,  0) #660000 srgb(102,0,0)
       144: ( 51,255,255) #33FFFF srgb(51,255,255)
       145: ( 51,255,204) #33FFCC srgb(51,255,204)
       146: ( 51,255,153) #33FF99 srgb(51,255,153)
       147: ( 51,255,102) #33FF66 srgb(51,255,102)
       148: ( 51,255, 51) #33FF33 srgb(51,255,51)
       149: ( 51,255,  0) #33FF00 srgb(51,255,0)
       150: ( 51,204,255) #33CCFF srgb(51,204,255)
       151: ( 51,204,204) #33CCCC srgb(51,204,204)
       152: ( 51,204,153) #33CC99 srgb(51,204,153)
       153: ( 51,204,102) #33CC66 srgb(51,204,102)
       154: ( 51,204, 51) #33CC33 srgb(51,204,51)
       155: ( 51,204,  0) #33CC00 srgb(51,204,0)
       156: ( 51,153,255) #3399FF srgb(51,153,255)
       157: ( 51,153,204) #3399CC srgb(51,153,204)
       158: ( 51,153,153) #339999 srgb(51,153,153)
       159: ( 51,153,102) #339966 srgb(51,153,102)
       160: ( 51,153, 51) #339933 srgb(51,153,51)
       161: ( 51,153,  0) #339900 srgb(51,153,0)
       162: ( 51,102,255) #3366FF srgb(51,102,255)
       163: ( 51,102,204) #3366CC srgb(51,102,204)
       164: ( 51,102,153) #336699 srgb(51,102,153)
       165: ( 51,102,102) #336666 srgb(51,102,102)
       166: ( 51,102, 51) #336633 srgb(51,102,51)
       167: ( 51,102,  0) #336600 srgb(51,102,0)
       168: ( 51, 51,255) #3333FF srgb(51,51,255)
       169: ( 51, 51,204) #3333CC srgb(51,51,204)
       170: ( 51, 51,153) #333399 srgb(51,51,153)
       171: ( 51, 51,102) #333366 srgb(51,51,102)
       172: ( 51, 51, 51) #333333 grey20
       173: ( 51, 51,  0) #333300 srgb(51,51,0)
       174: ( 51,  0,255) #3300FF srgb(51,0,255)
       175: ( 51,  0,204) #3300CC srgb(51,0,204)
       176: ( 51,  0,153) #330099 srgb(51,0,153)
       177: ( 51,  0,102) #330066 srgb(51,0,102)
       178: ( 51,  0, 51) #330033 srgb(51,0,51)
       179: ( 51,  0,  0) #330000 srgb(51,0,0)
       180: (  0,255,255) #00FFFF cyan
       181: (  0,255,204) #00FFCC srgb(0,255,204)
       182: (  0,255,153) #00FF99 srgb(0,255,153)
       183: (  0,255,102) #00FF66 srgb(0,255,102)
       184: (  0,255, 51) #00FF33 srgb(0,255,51)
       185: (  0,255,  0) #00FF00 lime
       186: (  0,204,255) #00CCFF srgb(0,204,255)
       187: (  0,204,204) #00CCCC srgb(0,204,204)
       188: (  0,204,153) #00CC99 srgb(0,204,153)
       189: (  0,204,102) #00CC66 srgb(0,204,102)
       190: (  0,204, 51) #00CC33 srgb(0,204,51)
       191: (  0,204,  0) #00CC00 srgb(0,204,0)
       192: (  0,153,255) #0099FF srgb(0,153,255)
       193: (  0,153,204) #0099CC srgb(0,153,204)
       194: (  0,153,153) #009999 srgb(0,153,153)
       195: (  0,153,102) #009966 srgb(0,153,102)
       196: (  0,153, 51) #009933 srgb(0,153,51)
       197: (  0,153,  0) #009900 srgb(0,153,0)
       198: (  0,102,255) #0066FF srgb(0,102,255)
       199: (  0,102,204) #0066CC srgb(0,102,204)
       200: (  0,102,153) #006699 srgb(0,102,153)
       201: (  0,102,102) #006666 srgb(0,102,102)
       202: (  0,102, 51) #006633 srgb(0,102,51)
       203: (  0,102,  0) #006600 srgb(0,102,0)
       204: (  0, 51,255) #0033FF srgb(0,51,255)
       205: (  0, 51,204) #0033CC srgb(0,51,204)
       206: (  0, 51,153) #003399 srgb(0,51,153)
       207: (  0, 51,102) #003366 srgb(0,51,102)
       208: (  0, 51, 51) #003333 srgb(0,51,51)
       209: (  0, 51,  0) #003300 srgb(0,51,0)
       210: (  0,  0,255) #0000FF blue
       211: (  0,  0,204) #0000CC srgb(0,0,204)
       212: (  0,  0,153) #000099 srgb(0,0,153)
       213: (  0,  0,102) #000066 srgb(0,0,102)
       214: (  0,  0, 51) #000033 srgb(0,0,51)
       215: (238,  0,  0) #EE0000 srgb(238,0,0)
       216: (221,  0,  0) #DD0000 srgb(221,0,0)
       217: (187,  0,  0) #BB0000 srgb(187,0,0)
       218: (170,  0,  0) #AA0000 srgb(170,0,0)
       219: (136,  0,  0) #880000 srgb(136,0,0)
       220: (119,  0,  0) #770000 srgb(119,0,0)
       221: ( 85,  0,  0) #550000 srgb(85,0,0)
       222: ( 68,  0,  0) #440000 srgb(68,0,0)
       223: ( 34,  0,  0) #220000 srgb(34,0,0)
       224: ( 17,  0,  0) #110000 srgb(17,0,0)
       225: (  0,238,  0) #00EE00 srgb(0,238,0)
       226: (  0,221,  0) #00DD00 srgb(0,221,0)
       227: (  0,187,  0) #00BB00 srgb(0,187,0)
       228: (  0,170,  0) #00AA00 srgb(0,170,0)
       229: (  0,136,  0) #008800 srgb(0,136,0)
       230: (  0,119,  0) #007700 srgb(0,119,0)
       231: (  0, 85,  0) #005500 srgb(0,85,0)
       232: (  0, 68,  0) #004400 srgb(0,68,0)
       233: (  0, 34,  0) #002200 srgb(0,34,0)
       234: (  0, 17,  0) #001100 srgb(0,17,0)
       235: (  0,  0,238) #0000EE srgb(0,0,238)
       236: (  0,  0,221) #0000DD srgb(0,0,221)
       237: (  0,  0,187) #0000BB srgb(0,0,187)
       238: (  0,  0,170) #0000AA srgb(0,0,170)
       239: (  0,  0,136) #000088 srgb(0,0,136)
       240: (  0,  0,119) #000077 srgb(0,0,119)
       241: (  0,  0, 85) #000055 srgb(0,0,85)
       242: (  0,  0, 68) #000044 srgb(0,0,68)
       243: (  0,  0, 34) #000022 srgb(0,0,34)
       244: (  0,  0, 17) #000011 srgb(0,0,17)
       245: (238,238,238) #EEEEEE srgb(238,238,238)
       246: (221,221,221) #DDDDDD srgb(221,221,221)
       247: (187,187,187) #BBBBBB srgb(187,187,187)
       248: (170,170,170) #AAAAAA srgb(170,170,170)
       249: (136,136,136) #888888 srgb(136,136,136)
       250: (119,119,119) #777777 srgb(119,119,119)
       251: ( 85, 85, 85) #555555 srgb(85,85,85)
       252: ( 68, 68, 68) #444444 srgb(68,68,68)
       253: ( 34, 34, 34) #222222 srgb(34,34,34)
       254: ( 17, 17, 17) #111111 srgb(17,17,17)
       255: (  0,  0,  0) #000000 black
  Rendering intent: Perceptual
  Gamma: 0.454545
  Chromaticity:
    red primary: (0.64,0.33)
    green primary: (0.3,0.6)
    blue primary: (0.15,0.06)
    white point: (0.3127,0.329)
  Background color: white
  Border color: srgb(223,223,223)
  Matte color: grey74
  Transparent color: black
  Interlace: None
  Intensity: Undefined
  Compose: Over
  Page geometry: 274x512+0+0
  Dispose: Undefined
  Iterations: 0
  Compression: None
  Orientation: TopLeft
  Properties:
    date:create: 2014-01-23T10:14:15+01:00
    date:modify: 2014-01-23T10:14:15+01:00
    exif:PixelXDimension: 274
    exif:PixelYDimension: 512
    signature: 8128db49ddcfd7d2a5076949c89c3ec525556e38ddad333ec6fed29dfe58f4fb
    tiff:endian: lsb
    tiff:photometric: palette
    tiff:rows-per-strip: 29
    tiff:software: Adobe Photoshop CC (Macintosh)
    tiff:timestamp: 2013:12:16 09:41:27
  Profiles:
    Profile-8bim: 6642 bytes
    Profile-exif: 398 bytes
    Profile-iptc: 15 bytes
      City[1,90]: 0x00000000: 254700                                        -%
      unknown[2,0]: 
  Artifacts:
    filename: test.tiff
    verbose: true
  Tainted: False
  Filesize: 149KB
  Number pixels: 140K
  Pixels per second: 35.07MB
  User time: 0.000u
  Elapsed time: 0:01.003
  Version: ImageMagick 6.8.7-10 Q16 x64 2013-12-08 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

Comment: Are you sure that there isn't a white background in your EPS? Can you post a link to your test file?

Comment: @nwellnhof How can I find this out? Or how can I make sure to create a transparent background? I tried Gimp and InkScape.

Comment: If your EPS images do not have transparency you could write a GIMP script that 1. loads the file 2. adds alpha channel 3. make a magic-select for pixel (1,1) if that belongs to the background 4. deletes 5. saves as PNG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the eps simply does not contain a transparent background. The colorspace with sRGB would be able to have transparency and GhostScript converting with `-sDEVICE=pngalpha` is also correct. In InkScape I created a red box, placed the eps on top and it has a white background there, too.

Finally I ended up removing the background like this:

```
convert -density 100 test.eps -flatten -fill none -floodfill +0+0 white test.png
```

`-fill none` sets the fill color to transparent and `-floodfill +0+0 white` starts a flood fill from the top, left corner. Filling up everything that is white. If it's not white nothing happens! You can user `-fuzz 50%` to also replace other background colors.

Also note that there is a [PHP lib for ImageMagick](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.floodfillpaintimage.php) for a cleaner solution.